# Can't resolve rubygems.org (too many redirects)

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, vagrant

For some reason my vagrant VM cannot resolve `rubygems.org`. It was working fine yesterday, today I made no changes and now it no longer works:

## Fresh Ubuntu install

```
vagrant -v # 1.5.3
vagrant init hashicorp/precise64 # ubuntu
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

## Installing ruby gems (fails)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rubygems -y

# here comes the failure...
sudo gem install librarian-puppet

"ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'librarian-puppet' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
too many redirects (http://www1.dlinksearch.com/?..."
```

## Can't resolve rubygems.org

```
wget rubygems.org 

"Resolving rubygems.org (rubygems.org)... ::ffff:67.215.65.145, 54.245.255.174
Connecting to rubygems.org (rubygems.org)|::ffff:67.215.65.145|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: http://www1.dlinksearch.com/?url=rubygems%2Eorg [following]
--2014-04-23 02:28:15--  http://www1.dlinksearch.com/?url=rubygems%2Eorg
Resolving www1.dlinksearch.com (www1.dlinksearch.com)... ::ffff:67.215.65.145, 
20 redirections exceeded."
```

## Other websites seem fine

```
wget google.com
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 173.194.126.8, 173.194.126.14, 173.194.126.2, ...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
2014-04-23 02:36:57 (651 KB/s) - `index.html.2' saved [13872]
```

## I can resolve by IP address

```
wget 54.245.255.174 
--2014-04-23 02:44:59--  http://rubygems.org/
Resolving rubygems.org (rubygems.org)... ::ffff:67.215.65.145, 54.245.255.174
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

## More Info

```
gem env 
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  ...
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - http://rubygems.org/
```

## It was working

- This was working fine yesterday night!
- The VM /etc/hosts seems fine
- I can access rubygems.org from my desktop browser without any issues
- Already tried destroying and creating a new vm
- Tried restarting my computer

Comment: A google search for 'dlinksearch' would seem to point to malware. Is your VM using your host for DNS resolution (resolv.conf)? Also what does reverse DNS say about the two IPs that are coming back for rubygems.org ? (Being on my phone currently, I don't have a terminal to play with)

Comment: @Charlie I will scan my computer for malware and try again!

Comment: @Charlie looks like it was a DNS issue with my Dlink router, apparently it has some type of dns cache that wasn't cleared, after doing a hard reset I can now resolve rubygems.org. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. thanks

Comment: Glad you got it cleared up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the comments, apparently there is a DNS caching issue, where "::ffff:67.215.65.145" was coming back as a valid address for rubygems. "54.245.255.174" is a valid address, as `dig @8.8.8.8 ANY rubygems.org` would reveal.